# How to force the parse (only one time ) of a Dojo's button [Err: widget is already registered]

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a function which adds a button to a div "dettaglio_utenti". After calling the function with this instruction

```
tab+="<button data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.Button' id='apri_mappa' onClick=\" location.href='tel:"+telefono+"'\">apri mappa</button>"

var vText = document.getElementById("dettaglio_utente");
    vText.innerHTML = tab;

require(["dojo/parser"], function(parser){
    parser.parse(vText);
});
```

It works only the first time that I display the page. The second time the button is not parsed and I see this error in the browser console: `dojo/parser::parse() error Error: Tried to register widget with id==apri_mappa but that id is already registered`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display the page for the second time, the first page must still be part of the dom. (Maybe this is a worklight feature, single page app?). So when dojo parses the second page it gives the error because the button with that id has already been created.

I don't believe preventing the parsing of the button a second time will accomplish what you need.  I think your options are:

1. Destroy the widgets from the first page.
2. If you don't need an id on the button, you can omit it and Dojo will create an id that won't collide.
3. If you need the id, you can or use a counter when emitting the id of the button.
   `id='apri_mappa_' + i` where i is the counter.

Only knowing what you wrote above, I think the order of preference is 2,1,3.

---

EDIT - How to destroy a widget

```
require(['dijit/registry'], function(registry) {
    registry.byId('apri_mappa').destroy();
});
```

Comment: Every time that I enter to this page, I call the function for create and parse the button. I delete id for now.. How i destroy the button and re-parse it ?

Comment: Do you need to create and parse each time you enter the page?  Once you created it, why not just reuse it?

Comment: Because the variabile vText have other data and values, don't contains only the button.Other Information change every time that i call the function

Comment: Have you built a custom widget before?  I think a better solution for what you are trying to do is to create a custom templated widget as opposed to building the content by concatenating strings.  With a custom widget this issue would go away, but I understand that there may be outside factors (time, etc) that would prevent you from going down this path.